# Doc and Docx files not upload in file upload in php and jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to upload a .doc, .docx file but it keeps on sending me an error in my console. Here is my script:

```
var formData = new FormData(document.forms['myRptForm']);
    $.ajax({
        url: myUrl,
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (res) {
            str = res.split("|");
            if(str[0]==0){
                alert('Sorry Files are not successfully Uploaded!');
            }else if(str[0]==1){
                alert('File are successfully Uploaded!');
                $('#userfile').val('').show();
            }else if(str[0]==2){
                alert(str[1]); $('#userfile').val('').show(); return false;
            }
            $('#myData').html(str[1]).show();
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        //error: function(err){
        //alert(err.status);
        //}
    });
```

Here is main-function.php:

Comment: what is the error you see in the console?

Comment: Instead of concatenating your data yourself using `|` symbols, you should look into json. And `main-function.php` is missing.